# how to make django manage a table that wasn't in the migration but in the database?

Tags: django, migration, migrate

Ok, where i work we are using a database that we would like to continue using but instead connect it to a different front end. Django 1.8

we did a inspectdb 
and we did a makemigration based on that information
and migrated

but still wont work. the other tables work fine but the other tables didn't exist before the migration (and wont taken from another database ) and the table we are looking at had information we wanted to keep for testing

the error we get is

```
column plans_to_lodge.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "plans_to_lodge"."id", "plans_to_lodge"."sm_sequence"...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question correctly, you wan't to use Django models with tables created outside Django, right?

It seems that you don't have the `id` column in that table. Django requires one PRIMARY KEY column or it will try to use `id` as a default.

Try setting an AutoField to a sutitable column:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: i added it
makemigration
migrate
table didnt update with it with the field so for sure i know that table isnt synced

Comment: Are you pointing the model to a right table: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#db-table?

Comment: yea it was named the same and in the class meta. all lower case it just refused to use it. now ive moved on what im trying to do is pg_restore the information from that table to a table (exactly the same ) but was created by django. and my pg_restore tells me it cant find any files in "C:\backup
note its just the data for the table